# Curly Braces in C# Method

Tags: c#, object-initializers

I'm currently programming in C# and found this snippet in one of the tutorials.

What exactly do the curly braces in this method mean? Is it like a key value pair `{id: 2}`?

```
weapon = new Weapon(new WeaponData() { Id = 12 });
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `new WeaponData() { }`, just `new WeaponData { }`

Comment: Take a look at Microsofts documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what's called an obect initializer. It allows you to set the values of properties right after the obect is constructed. It's equivalent to the following code:

```
var weaponData = new WeaponData();
weaponData.Id = 12;
weapon = new Weapon(weaponData);
```

Comment: I'd upvote, but the duplicate I marked has much, much more details to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `weapon` class has a no args constructor which is being called, in the same line, its initialising the `id` property with a value of 12. Its just another way of initialising the object